# How can you change the variable that data is assigned to each time the loop progresses?

Tags: python, variables

this is the example of the program

```
hello1,hello2,hello3,hello4,hello5=(),(),(),(),()
a_list=[hello1,hello2,hello3,hello4,hello5]
greetingslist= ["hello","good morning","good evening","afternoon","hi"]
for i range 5:
    a_list[i]=greetingslist[i]
```

so I want each variable identifier to be different so that each can be assigned something. However it doesn't recognize the `[i]` next to the variable so an error occurs.

I don't want to change the program much or make it too complicated, but I would like this to be done within one loop...is there any way I could do this???

thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless really necessary, I would suggest you use python dictionaries instead https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: The short answer is, don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just storing references to your variables, which you override in the loop. If you want to dynamically set the variables by their name, you'll have to use `globals()`/`locals()`/`setattr()` in dependence of the namespace, e.g.:

```
greetings_list = ["hello", "good morning", "good evening", "afternoon", "hi"]

for i, v in enumerate(greetings_list):
    locals()["hello" + str(i + 1)] = v

print(hello1)  # hello
print(hello2)  # good morning
print(hello3)  # good evening
print(hello4)  # afternoon
# etc.
```

Not that it's a recommended style or anything, far from it, but that's how you can do it.